# Passing current object in a forEach to a function

Tags: javascript, json, object

For some reason if I have an object which looks like this:

```
let clients = [{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "Felipe",
  "last_name": "Aiken",
  "email": "faiken0@360.cn",
  "gender": "Male",
  "ip_address": "13.189.73.39"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "first_name": "Renell",
  "last_name": "Andreone",
  "email": "randreone1@histats.com",
  "gender": "Female",
  "ip_address": "196.153.244.124"
}];
```

and then use in a forEach loop like so:

```
clients.forEach(function(client) {
    console.log(client);
    let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
    let newObj = {
        'name': 'client.first_name'
    };
    tbody.innerHTML = tbody.innerHTML + '\
        <tr>\
            <td>' + client.id + '</td>\
            <td>' + client.first_name + '</td>\
            <td>' + client.last_name + '</td>\
            <td>' + client.email + '</td>\
            <td>' + client.gender + '</td>\
            <td><button onclick="setClientInfo(' + (newObj) + ')" class="btn btn-primary">View</td>\
        </tr>\
    ';
});
```

when I click the "View" button for any of the items I get an, "Unexpected error" for the following code in the console:

```
setClientInfo([object Object])
```

The setClientInfo function simply looks like this:

```
function setClientInfo(client) {
    console.log(client);
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: When you add an object to a string, like that, it adds the value of `.toString()`, not the object.  Use `onclick="setClientInfo(' + client.id + ')"` and then parse `clients` in the function and find the client by the id.  (If you try to find them by first name then you can only have 1 person with that first name.)

Comment: When you inspect your button HTML after it is created, you will see that it likely says '[object Object]' where you think the object is being placed in the onclick. Archer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As our friend **@Archer** said in the comments, pass the `client.id` to the function `setClientInfo`, then inside that function, find the client you need using that `id`.
The code below helps with that.

```js
let clients = [{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "Felipe",
  "last_name": "Aiken",
  "email": "faiken0@360.cn",
  "gender": "Male",
  "ip_address": "13.189.73.39"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "first_name": "Renell",
  "last_name": "Andreone",
  "email": "randreone1@histats.com",
  "gender": "Female",
  "ip_address": "196.153.244.124"
}];

clients.forEach(function(client) {
    let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
    let newObj = {
        'name': 'client.first_name'
    };
    tbody.innerHTML = tbody.innerHTML + '\
        <tr>\
            <td>' + client.id + '</td>\
            <td>' + client.first_name + '</td>\
            <td>' + client.last_name + '</td>\
            <td>' + client.email + '</td>\
            <td>' + client.gender + '</td>\
            <td><button onclick="setClientInfo(' + client.id + ')" class="btn btn-primary">View</td>\
        </tr>\
    ';
});

function setClientInfo(clientId){
  console.log(clientId)
  var client = clients.find(x => x.id == clientId);
  console.log(client)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Another way would be creating the elements not using a string and appending via `innerHTML` but creating the element itself with `document.createElement()`, then you can assign the listener passing the obj as a parameter. Like below:

```js
let clients = [{
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Felipe",
      "last_name": "Aiken",
      "email": "faiken0@360.cn",
      "gender": "Male",
      "ip_address": "13.189.73.39"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Renell",
      "last_name": "Andreone",
      "email": "randreone1@histats.com",
      "gender": "Female",
      "ip_address": "196.153.244.124"
    }];

    clients.forEach(function(client) {
        let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
        let newObj = {
            'name': 'client.first_name'
        };
        var trElem = document.createElement("tr");

        //LOOPING TRHOUGH ALL CLIENT PROPERTIES
        for (var prop in client){
            var tdElem =  document.createElement("td");
            tdElem.textContent = client[prop];
            trElem.append(tdElem)            
        }      

        //Create the last td with the Button
        var tdClick = document.createElement("td");
        var btn = document.createElement("button")
        tdClick.append(btn);
        btn.onclick = setClientInfo.bind(this, client)
        btn.className = "btn btn-primary";
        btn.textContent = "View"
        trElem.append(tdClick);
        
        //Append to table body
        tbody.append(trElem);
    });

    function setClientInfo(client){
      console.log(client)
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That makes so much more sense append the elements instead of using the innerHTML method. This works a treat and definitely solves the issue I was having. Thank you very much for your help with this @CalvinNunes

Answer (score 0):

onclick handler is rendered as string on html, so by default object literal is rendered as `[object Object]`, just try to run this in dev console:

```
"" + {key: "value"}
```

result looks like:

```
<button onclick="setClientInfo([object Object])" />
```

handler is not valid JS, which is reported by error. If you really want to inline object value to HTML then you can change `newObject` to string type like:

```
let newObj = "{'name': 'client.first_name'}";
```

so your handler will look like:

```
<button onclick="setClientInfo({'name': 'client.first_name'})" />
```

In general it is still bad idea. As already mentioned other answer/comments, it is much better to pass just identifier to click handler function and use it to find required object in JS code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will bear this one in mind for future reference. I have opted to go with the new approach of appending the elements instead of using innerHTML, as suggested by Calvin Nunes and this seems to work perfectly. Thanks again for your suggestion!